# $u=0$ a.e. on compact sets $K\subset \Omega$ implies $u=0$ a.e on $\Omega$.

Tags: measure-theory

In the proof of Lemma de Du Bois Raymond in Brézis's Book (Functional Analysis, Corollary 4.24), he claims that:

> If $u=0$ a.e. on all compact sets $K\subset \Omega$, then $u=0$ a.e on $\Omega$, where $\Omega$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$.

I've seen this in some book, but I can't find it. Anyone could provide a proof of this fact or give me a reference?

Comment: Do you mean for all compact sets $K$?

Comment: Isn't any open set in $\Bbb R^n$ contained within a countable union of compact sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any open set in $\Bbb R^n$ is a countable union of compact sets.  To see this, recall that open balls of rational radius centered on points with rational coordinates form a countable basis for the standard topology on $\Bbb R^n$, and then note that any open ball of radius $r$ is the union of closed balls of radius $r-\frac 1n$, which is a countable union of compact sets.

Let $E= \{ x \in \Omega \mid u(x) \neq 0 \} $.  Then $E$ is contained within a countable union of sets of measure zero, so $\mu(E)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The Lebesgue measure is regular, meaning that the measure of $E\subseteq\Omega$ is equal to $$\sup\{m(K)|K\subseteq E,K\text{ compact}\}$$
In particular, let $E=\{u(x)\neq0\}$, then $m(K)=0$ for every $K\subseteq E$ (by hypothesis, since $u=0$ almost everywhere in $K$), so $m(E)=0$.